# How to get the real $k$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**In an exercise I am asked:**

*Consider the function $f(x)=kx$ if $1<x<5$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise.*

*What value must the real $k$ take so that $f(x)$ is a function of uniform density?*

---

For $f(x)$ to be uniform, for any value of $x$ of the range, $f(x)$ must always be equal. But from there on, I do not know how to solve it.

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are two conditions any density function has to respect: 1.) $f(x)\geq 0 $ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and 2.) $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx =1$. One of these conditions will implie the value $k$.
edit: f(x) will never be the density of a uniform random variable (its value should be constant on $1<x<5$). are you sure you don't mean F(x)?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int^5_1 kx~ dx =1$$

$$ \frac{kx^2}{2}|^5_1=1$$

$$ \frac{25k}{2}-\frac{k}{2}=1$$

$$12k=1$$

$$ \therefore k=\frac{1}{12}$$